# IF/ElseIf for different input parameter in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

PHP/MySQL

Assume the connection and the basic SQL Statement "SELECT .... FROM DB " is already established. I have 3 scenarios wanna achieve as below input by user in the web browser:

1. //...../xxx.php?Ticker=APPL
2. //...../xxx.php?Ticker=APPL&StartDate=20140901&EndDate=20140902
3. //...../xxx.php?StartDate=20140901&EndDate=20140902

For Scenario 1, it will have a where cluase in sql statement -> where Ticker = APPL

For Scenario 2, it will have a where cluase in sql statement -> where Ticker = APPL and date(ReleaseDT) BETWEEN '$StartDate' AND '$EndDate'

For Scenario 3, just bound by the date period.

Assuming I have $SQL = " " <- already have the basic select statement until FROM DB, But I get nothing returned in browser. Please help.

```
$Ticker = htmlspecialchars($_GET["Ticker"]);
$StartDate = htmlspecialchars($_GET["StartDate"]);
$EndDate = htmlspecialchars($_GET["EndDate"]);

IF ($Ticker != Null && $StartDate === Null)
    {
        $SQL = $SQL . " WHERE Ticker = '$Ticker' ";
    }
ElseIf ($Ticker != Null && $StartDate != Null)
    {
        $SQL = $SQL . " WHERE Ticker = '$Ticker' AND Date(ReleaseDT) BETWEEN '$StartDate' AND '$EndDate' ";
    }
ElseIf  ($Ticker == Null && $StartDate != Null)
    {
        $SQL = $SQL . " WHERE Date(ReleaseDT) BETWEEN '$StartDate' AND '$EndDate' ";
    }
}

$SQL = $SQL & " GROUP BY Ticker, date(ReleaseDT) ORDER BY date(ReleaseDT) DESC";

 ECHO $SQL;

$data = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: This is not valid php. You should be appending your strings with a '.' and not a '&'. You should be using the more secure mysqli functions rather than the mysql functions. If this is your complete code you are missing the 'Select' statement at the beginning

Comment: Not sure who down voted but it was not me. I would assume this was down voted because you are expected to do research on the topic before posting and show your results to help others find a solution to your problem. The first thing would be to get the script written in valid php.

Comment: I am just beginner in php, if I know, I don't need to ask. It's so demotivate to because of this reason to down vote. It's not about right or wrong. I think be positive is better. Especially for beginners trying to earn reputation.

Besides, I think you shall really see it and give suggestion. I have changed it to "." instead of "&" but still returned nothing.

[Will update the above]

Comment: Nevermind, no method. Deducted is deducted. But the good side is I know it now and won't commit again. Somehow need to work most of the time and study not only programming at the same time. So 2 downvote is for the tuition fee =.="

Comment: Well there are a lot more issues with this script that what I stated above. I don't see any code to establish a connection with your mysql database.

Comment: I have established the connection and basic sql statement, which must be correct. I just want to learn how to distinguish what user input and then varied my SQL string dynamically in php. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would build each `WHERE` clause-part individually, for example;

```
$Ticker = isset($_GET['Ticker']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET["Ticker"]) : NULL;
$StartDate = isset($_GET['StartDate']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET["StartDate"]) : NULL;
$EndDate = isset($_GET['EndDate']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET["EndDate"]) : NULL;

if($Ticker != NULL) {
    $SQL .= " WHERE Ticker = '$Ticker' ";
}
if($StartDate != NULL AND $EndDate != NULL) {
    $SQL .= (($Ticker) 
                ? " AND " 
                : " WHERE ") ." Date(ReleaseDT) BETWEEN '$StartDate' AND '$EndDate' ";
}

$SQL = $SQL . " GROUP BY Ticker, date(ReleaseDT) ORDER BY date(ReleaseDT) DESC";

echo $SQL;

$data = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());
```

**Could you mind explaining further on this part**

`$SQL .= (($Ticker) ? " AND " : " WHERE ")`

This uses a [ternary operator](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators). In long, it's basically;

```
if($Ticker) { } else { }
```

- [My other answer to do with ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20747553/3000179)

Comment: $SQL .= (($Ticker) 
                ? " AND " 
                : " WHERE ")

Could you mind explaining further on this part? thanks